# sed to find and replace a value in xml file

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I have to run with sed for this job, without knowing the value (xxx), but only the attribute (`revision`)

```
<types name="foo" revision="xxx">
```

to

```
<types name="foo" revision="5678">
```

my first try is:

```
sed 's@(revision=\").*@\1$5678\">@'
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following `sed` approach:

```
sed -Ei 's~( revision=")[^"]+"~\15678"~g' test.xml
```

`-E` option, allows extended regular expresssion

`-i` option, allows modifying the file *in place*

Answer (score 2):

You probably can get done with `sed` (in very simple cases) but for editing `xml` here are better (and error prone) tools, like `xmlstarlet`. Using it is simple:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//types/@revision" -v 5678 old.xml >new.xml
```

EDIT:

Alernative solution using `perl` & [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-LibXML) module:

```
perl -MXML::LibXML -E '$d=XML::LibXML->load_xml(location=>q{file.xml});$_->setAttribute(q{revision},4567)for$d->findnodes(q{//types[@revision]});say $d'
```

Comment: `++` for the right approach. `sed` is not recommended for `XML` manipulation

Comment: thanks, jm666, but I'm running in a pretty limited setup, only sed is available.

Comment: @pepero YMMV, but wondering which platform (setup) haven't for example `perl`. :) even on rPI could have `perl`. The solution is similar using some `XML/XPath` perl modules...

Comment: @jm666, well, a tool is too much to do a "sed" job. also we have to policy to respect to install anything.